# GET request in Node and React to check login information

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, get

I'm making a MERN application. I'm fairly new to it, so I'm trying to make everything based on what I know without looking much stuff up, because if I follow tutorials too much I don't remember stuff. Anyway, I've got a component that sends the registration information to the database and everything there is okay. Now I'm trying to check the login.

When I make the "GET" request to a route that I named "/check", nothing happens. If I change it to a "POST" request, things work. Shouldn't it be a "GET" request though since I'm trying to get information from the database?

The Node file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const application = express();
application.use(express.json());
application.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

mongoose.connect(process.env.PASSWORD)
    .then(console.log('Database connected'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

const db = mongoose.connection;

application.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello World');
});

application.post('/post', (request, response) => {
    db.collection('data').insertOne({
        name: request.body.username,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(request.body.password, 10),
    }).then(console.log('Submission done'));
    console.log('POST made');
    response.redirect('/');
});

application.get('/check', (request, response) => {
    db.collection('data').findOne({
        name: request.body.username,
        password: bcrypt.compareSync(
            request.body.password,
            bcrypt.hashSync(request.body.password, 10)
        ),
    });
    console.log('The request went through');
    response.redirect('/');
});

application.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening here...');
});
```

The React file:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Login = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <h1 className="text-center">Login</h1>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col"></div>
            <div className="col text-center">
                <form action="/check" method="GET">
                    <label for="username" name="username">Username: </label>
                    <input name="username" className="h4" />
                    <label for="password" name="password">Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" className="h4" />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="col"></div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Forms have a default behavior you need to override when a `button` is inside a `form` tag. I believe you need to `event.preventDefault()` to stop the forms default behavior from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between the "GET" and "POST" of HTML `form` element and "GET" and "POST" of node.js .

From Node.js perspective, you can save/send data to database with both POST and GET. However, the situtation is different for `form` element.

If you use "GET" on the `form` element, then `form` will submit all input data to the URL. And on the node.js side, you will need to use `req.query` to get data on the url, not `req.body`

So, in your code, you are using "GET" for the `Form` element but on the node.js file, you are using `req.body`. This shouldn't work.

Even if you make it work with `req.query`, the situation will still be totally unsafe, as you openly showing the passwords on the URL.

For  more info, on html `form` attributes, this link can be useful. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

you are sending username and password to the server so you should to use POST method